# Material ui library margin bottom problem

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, rxjs

**Hi Everyone**, Many Greetings from Turkey.

firstly this is my App.js Codes

```
/* React Imports*/
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

/*Local Imports */
import { ColorModeContext, useMode } from "./theme";
import Dashboard from "./WorkPages/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Topbar from "./WorkPages/GlobalPages/Topbar";
import Sidebar from "./WorkPages/GlobalPages/Sidebar";
import Team from "./WorkPages/Team/Team";
import CreateNewUser from "./WorkPages/CreateNewUser/CreateNewUser";
import Projects from "./WorkPages/Projects/Projects";
import CreateNewProjects from "./WorkPages/CreateNewProject/CreateNewProject";
import Bar from "./WorkPages/BarChart/BarChart";
import PieChart from "./WorkPages/PieChart/PieChart";
import LineChartGraph from "./WorkPages/LineChartGraph/LineChartGraph";
import TeamLocation from "./WorkPages/TeamLocation/TeamLocation";
import ProductBooks from "./WorkPages/ProductBooks/ProductBooks";
import WorkPlan from "./WorkPages/WorkPlan/WorkPlan";
import RoomInfoInput from "./WorkPages/RoomInfoInput/RoomInfoInput";
import StairsInfoInput from "./WorkPages/StairsInfoInput/StairsInfoInput";
import Specifications from "./WorkPages/Specifications/Specifications";
import InteractiveDB from "./WorkPages/InteractiveDB/InteractiveDB";
import Multiplication from "./WorkPages/Multiplication/Multiplication";
import ImportData from "./WorkPages/ImportData/ImportData";
import ExportData from "./WorkPages/ExportData/ExportData";
import HelpMenu from "./WorkPages/HelpMenu/HelpMenu";

/*MUI Imports */
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import BarChart from "./components/_BarChart";
import Tabs from "@mui/material/Tabs";

function App() {
    const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();
    const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);
    return (
        <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Tabs>
                    <div className="app">
                        <Sidebar isSidebar={isSidebar} />
                        <main className="content">
                            <Topbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar} />
                            <Routes>
                                <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
                                <Route path="/team" element={<Team />} />
                                <Route
                                    path="/createnewuser"
                                    element={<CreateNewUser />}
                                />
                                <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
                                <Route
                                    path="/createnewproject"
                                    element={<CreateNewProjects />}
                                />
                                <Route path="/barchart" element={<BarChart />} />
                                <Route path="/piechart" element={<PieChart />} />
                                <Route path="/linechart" element={<LineChartGraph />} />
                                <Route
                                    path="/teamlocation"
                                    element={<TeamLocation />}
                                />
                                <Route
                                    path="/productbooks"
                                    element={<ProductBooks />}
                                />
                                <Route path="/workplan" element={<WorkPlan />} />
                                <Route
                                    path="/roominfoinput"
                                    element={<RoomInfoInput />}
                                />
                                <Route
                                    path="/stairsinfoinput"
                                    element={<StairsInfoInput />}
                                />
                                <Route
                                    path="/specifications"
                                    element={<Specifications />}
                                />
                                <Route
                                    path="/interactivedb"
                                    element={<InteractiveDB />}
                                />
                                <Route
                                    path="/multiplication"
                                    element={<Multiplication />}
                                />
                                <Route path="/importdata" element={<ImportData />} />
                                <Route path="/exportdata" element={<ExportData />} />
                                <Route path="/helpmenu" element={<HelpMenu />} />
                            </Routes>
                        </main>
                    </div>
                </Tabs>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

My index.css codes

```
/* Google Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');




/* CSS CODES*/
html,
body,
#root,
.app,
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Default Font Will be "Source Sans Pro" */
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

/* Scroll Bar Setting */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track Bar Setting */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

/* Handle Setting */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

/* Handle On Hover Setting */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

and current view of my project on the browser
[image: as you can see there is a space at the bottom]

How can I fix this problem with css codes or without css so with MUI classes? I tried many way to fix that but I didn't get a solution.

I tried

```
overflow:hidden
```

code lines but they're doesn't working for my problem.
[image: 50% screen size in my laptop]

here is my sidebar codes

```js
/*REACT IMPORTS*/
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

/*MUI IMPORTS*/
import { Box, IconButton, Typography, useTheme } from "@mui/material";

/*MUI ICONS IMPORTS*/
import MenuOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MenuOutlined";
import HomeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HomeOutlined";
import EngineeringOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/EngineeringOutlined";
import FoundationOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FoundationOutlined";
import BarChartOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/BarChartOutlined";
import DonutSmallOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DonutSmallOutlined";
import StackedLineChartOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/StackedLineChartOutlined";
import LocationSearchingOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LocationSearchingOutlined";
import MenuBookOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MenuBookOutlined";
import CalendarMonthOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CalendarMonthOutlined";
import InputOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/InputOutlined";
import StairsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/StairsOutlined";
import LibraryBooksOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LibraryBooksOutlined";
import StorageOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/StorageOutlined";
import DynamicFeedOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DynamicFeedOutlined";
import FileUploadOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FileUploadOutlined";
import FileDownloadOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FileDownloadOutlined";
import HelpOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutlined";

/*LOCAL IMPORTS*/
import { tokens } from "../../theme";

/*OTHER IMPORTS MAIN COMMENT*/

/*REACT PRO SIDEBAR IMPORTS*/
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem } from "react-pro-sidebar";
import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";

/*-----------Components--------------*/

const Item = ({ title, to, icon, selected, setSelected }) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
    return (
        <MenuItem
            active={selected == title}
            style={{ color: colors.grey[100] }}
            onClick={() => setSelected(title)}
            icon={icon}>
            <Typography>{title}</Typography>
            <Link to={to} />
        </MenuItem>
    );
};

const Sidebar = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
    const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Dashboard");

    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                "& .pro-siderbar-inner": {
                    background: `${colors.primary[400]} !important`,
                },
                "& .pro-icon-wrapper": {
                    backgroundColor: "transparent ! important",
                },
                "& .pro-inner-item": {
                    padding: "5px 35px 5px 20px !important",
                },
                "& .pro-inner-item:hover": {
                    color: "#F08221 !important",
                },
                "& .pro-menu-item.active": {
                    colors: "#6870fa !important",
                },
            }}>
            <ProSidebar collapsed={isCollapsed}>
                {/* COMPANY LOGO AND MENU ICON */}
                <Menu iconShape='square'>
                    <MenuItem
                        onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}
                        icon={
                            isCollapsed ? (
                                <MenuOutlinedIcon fontSize='large' />
                            ) : undefined
                        }
                        style={{ margin: "10px 0 20px 0", color: colors.grey[100] }}>
                        {!isCollapsed && (
                            <Box
                                display='flex'
                                justifyContent='space-between'
                                alignItems='center'
                                ml='15px'
                                overflow='hidden'>
                                <Typography variant='h3'>Metraj Merkezi</Typography>
                                <IconButton
                                    onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}>
                                    <MenuOutlinedIcon fontSize='large' />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Box>
                        )}
                    </MenuItem>

                    {!isCollapsed && (
                        <Box mb='25px'>
                            <Box
                                display='flex'
                                justifyContent='center'
                                alignItems='center'>
                                <img
                                    alt='profile-user'
                                    width='100px'
                                    height='100px'
                                    src={`../../assets/fikret.jpg`}
                                    style={{ cursor: "pointer", borderRadius: "50%" }}
                                />
                            </Box>
                            <Box textAlign='center'>
                                <Typography variant='h3' color={colors.grey[100]}>
                                    Fikret AKBAŞ
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography variant='h6' color={colors.grey[500]}>
                                    Metraj Merkezi CEO
                                </Typography>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    )}
                    <Box paddingLeft={isCollapsed ? undefined : "10%"}>
                        <Item
                            title='Anasayfa'
                            to='/'
                            icon={<HomeOutlinedIcon fontSize='large' />}
                            selected={selected}
                            setSelected={setSelected}
                        />
                        <Typography
                            variant='h6'
                            color={colors.grey[300]}
                            sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}>
                            Yönetici Paneli
                        </Typography>
                        <Item
                            title='Takımı Yönet'
                            to='/team'
                            icon={<EngineeringOutlinedIcon fontSize='large' />}
                            selected={selected}
                            setSelected={setSelected}
                        />
             ... there are  many items but I didn't add here for too long waste codes here
                    </Box>
                </Menu>
            </ProSidebar>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

here is my Topbar codes

```js
/*REACT IMPORTS*/
import { useContext } from "react";


/*MUI IMPORTS*/
import { Box, IconButton, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";

/*MUI ICONS IMPORTS*/
import LightModeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LightModeOutlined";
import DarkModeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DarkModeOutlined";
import NotificationsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NotificationsOutlined";
import SettingsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SettingsOutlined";
import PersonOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlined";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import FolderSharedOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FolderSharedOutlined";
import FactCheckOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FactCheckOutlined";


/*LOCAL IMPORTS*/
import { ColorModeContext, tokens } from "../../theme";

/*OTHER IMPORTS MAIN COMMENT*/
/*OTHER IMPORTS*/




/*-----------Components--------------*/

const Topbar = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const colorMode = useContext(ColorModeContext);

  return (
    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" p={2}>
      {/* SEARCH BAR */}
      <Box
        display="flex"
        backgroundColor={colors.primary[700]}
        borderRadius="3px"
      >
        <InputBase sx={{ ml: 2, flex: 1 }} placeholder="Search" />
        <IconButton type="button" sx={{ p: 1 }}>
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>

      {/* ICONS */}
      <Box display="flex" border="1px solid" borderRadius={3}>
        <IconButton onClick={colorMode.toggleColorMode}>
          {theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? (
            <LightModeOutlinedIcon />
          ) : (
            <DarkModeOutlinedIcon />
          )}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <FactCheckOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>

        <IconButton>
          <FolderSharedOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <NotificationsOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <SettingsOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <PersonOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Topbar;
```

Comment: Hi Fikret, please can you brief your problem and what do you want to do?

Comment: Hi Tolga, firstly thank you so much for your response. I'd like to remove space of bottom. I don't wanna have a scroll in my project pages, in addition to fit all of component in the screen.

Comment: in addition to fit all of component in the screen. I'm monitoring different views in different devices. I don't know why. How can I fix it globally?

Comment: Lastly can you edit your question and add related component which includes your sidebar, header says material ui but I can't see any mui component, after that I will recommend a few ways

Comment: Dear Tolga, Thanks again for your reply. I added the components which are related each other.